# what is redefining static variable in c++?

Tags: c++, static, data-members

It's said that,
**Once the definition for static data member is made, user cannot redefine it.**
what does it exactly mean? As I am able to assign anything to it

```
#include<iostream.h>
class X
{
    public:
       static int i;
    X()
    {
        i = 2;    //no error in initializing it in constructor
    };
};

int X::i=1;

int main()
{
   X obj;
   cout << obj.i;   // prints 2, no prob. occur
   obj.i = 3;
   cout << obj.i;   // prints 3, same runs fine 
   X::i = 10;
   cout<<obj.i;     // prints 10, still no error
   return 0;
}
```

if **assigning value and redefining are different**, then what is redefining a static or a even a normal variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Inside the class is the *declaration*. Outside the class is the *definition* and *initialization*. In the constructor is an *assignment*.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. OP seems to be thinking that `static` and `const` are synonymous. When he said "redefine" I think he meant "assign".

Comment: Actually, I want to know what is **Redefining** a variable? and why are static variables cant be redefined

Comment: I echo the sentiment of @Care

Comment: Previous comment got tangled up in some Javascript hell and I couldn't edit it.  I echo the sentiment of Carey Gregory and Prasanna Thapa - this is a variation on that question, not a duplicate.  The semantics of "static" make this worthy of a separate answer, IMHO.